# Copy Paste userinput

Tags: android, onclick, user-input, gettext, settext

I'm working on an exercise and I am stock right now.
I have to Copy the Userinput and then Paste the String created.
Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
public class CopyPasteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button CopyButton;
    private Button PasteButton;
    private EditText UserInput;
    private TextView PasteText;
    private final static String TAG = "CopyPasteActivity";

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_copy_paste);

        CopyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.copy_button);
        PasteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paste_button);
        UserInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_input);
        PasteText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paste_text);

        final String userinput = new String();

        CopyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "The button Copy was pressed");
               String userinput = UserInput.getText().toString();
            }
        });

        PasteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "The button True was pressed");
                PasteText.setText(userinput);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the exact issue you are facing ?

Comment: It has to take the Userinput and Copy it to a String. Then it should set the text in a TextView when you click the Paste Button. I don't know if it is the Copy function or Paste function that doesn't work?

Comment: carlpoole's answer is correct, refer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring `userinput` inside `onCreate()` and making it `final`, which prevents you from editing it later. Also inside the `CopyButton` `click listener` you are creating a new local variable for `userinput` whose scope is limited to that listener only.

Move `String userinput = new String();` outside of `onCreate()`, removing `final`, and change the line in the `CopyButton` listener to

```
userinput = UserInput.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not define your `userinput` variable inside your `CopyButton.setOnClickListener`. define it as your as class or instance variable outside your listener so that your `PasteButton.setOnClickListener` should see it. like this:

```
String userinput;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_copy_paste);

    CopyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.copy_button);
    PasteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paste_button);
    UserInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_input);
    PasteText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paste_text);

    CopyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "The button Copy was pressed");
            userinput = UserInput.getText().toString();
        }
    });

    PasteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "The button True was pressed");
            PasteText.setText(userinput);
        }
    });
}
```